# Trying to make a trapezoidish looking shape with canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on creating a trapezoid looking shape with `Canvas`, but I am very new to it. In fact. This is my first time using it. I seem to have hit a snag with with my shape and i am not exactly sure how to fix it. Could anyone help?

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/auwgr/

**--- EDIT ---**

I realized that I didnt really provide any clarification on what I was trying to accomplish. Here is an image of what i would like the shape to look like:

[image]

Kinda like that (sorry for my drawing skills or lack of drawing skills)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw your rounded-trapezoid using a canvas path.

[image]

This path has 4 parts:

- top-arc: sweeping from top-left to top-right
- right-line: from the end of top-arc to the right of bottom-arc
- bottom-arc: sweeping from bottom-right to bottom left
- left-line: closes the path between the bottom-left and top left arcs.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kqY8D/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // canvas references
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // the centerpoint of the arc-trapezoid
    var cx=150;
    var cy=150;

    // the inside and outside radii
    var insideRadius=60;
    var outsideRadius=100;

    // the beginning and ending angles 
    var beginningAngle=Math.PI*5/4;
    var endingAngle=Math.PI*7/4;

    // use trigonometry to calculate the starting point
    // of the bottom leftward sweeping arc
    var x=cx+insideRadius*Math.cos(endingAngle);
    var y=cy+insideRadius*Math.sin(endingAngle);

    // set the path style
    ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    ctx.lineWidth=2;

    // begin the path

    ctx.beginPath();

    // top-arc: sweeping from top-left to top-right

    ctx.arc(cx,cy,outsideRadius,beginningAngle,endingAngle);

    // right-line: from the end of top-arc to the right of bottom-arc

    ctx.lineTo(x,y);

    // bottom-arc: sweeping from bottom-right to bottom left
    // (Note: the true on the end causes the arc to sweep right to left

    ctx.arc(cx,cy,insideRadius,endingAngle,beginningAngle,true);

    // left-line: closes the path between the
    // bottom-left and top left arcs.

    ctx.closePath();

    // stroke the path

    ctx.stroke();

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that I could split it up into 4 parts like that. Thank you!

Comment: But also, I was wondering if you would be able to tell me how I would fill the shape? I tried using `.fillStyle` and had no luck.

Comment: Sure, you can use .fillStyle to set the fill color and .fill to do the actual filling: ctx.fillStyle="lightblue";
ctx.fill();  I've updated the Fiddle to show filling: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kqY8D/

Comment: So i guess i have to set the fill after i stroke the path? I originally had it set up before.

Comment: The way all context styles work is that they remain in effect until new styles are set.  So you can context.fillStyle and context.strokeStyle once in advance.  Then every subsequest fill() and stroke() will use those styles. If you then want a different stroke or fill color, you just do context.fillStyle/context.strokeStyle again.  Note: you only get 1 styling for each context.beginPath.  So beginpath+fillStyle="red"+rect+fillStyle="blue"+rect+fill will have 2 blue rects and no red rects.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! This was very informative for me!